# Reduce the size of the file while I write an array to GeoTIFF using Python

Tags: python

I want to change the label of a GeoTIFF array.

This is what I am doing

```py
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal

    def changeLabel(arr):
        arr[np.where( arr == 103 )] = 10        # class 1
        arr[np.where( arr == 33 )]  = 20        # class 2
        arr[np.where( arr == 65 )]  = 30        # class 3
        arr[np.where( arr == 1 )]   = 40        # class 4
        arr[np.where( arr == 9 )]   = 50        # class 5
        arr[np.where( arr == 17 )]  = 60        # class 6
        arr[np.where( arr == 129 )] =  0        # water / no data
        return arr

    def distanceFile(inFile, outFile):
        driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
        file = gdal.Open(inFile)
        band = file.GetRasterBand(1)
        lista = band.ReadAsArray()
        lista = changeLabel(lista)
    
        # create new file
        file2 = driver.Create(outFile, file.RasterXSize , file.RasterYSize , 1)
        b = file2.GetRasterBand(1)
        b.SetNoDataValue(0)
        b.SetNoDataValue(1)
        b.WriteArray(lista)
    
        # spatial ref system
        proj = file.GetProjection()
        georef = file.GetGeoTransform()
        file2.SetProjection(proj)
        file2.SetGeoTransform(georef)
        file2 = None

    inFile='inFile.tif'
    outFile='outFile.tif'
    ## Run the function
    distanceFile(inFile,outFile)
```

However while `inFile` has a size of `150 MB`, the `outFile` size is `6.7 GB`. How can I reduce the size of the produced file?

Comment: Use compressed TIFF as output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use a sensible data type (UInt8 should work for your data) and compress the output. You can do this with the `Create` statement, and use LZW (or DEFLATE) compression:

```py
file2 = driver.Create(outFile, xsize=file.RasterXSize, 
                     ysize=file.RasterYSize, bands=1,
                     eType=gdal.GDT_Byte,
                     options=['COMPRESS=LZW']
                     )
```

See more details about compression options [here](https://kokoalberti.com/articles/geotiff-compression-optimization-guide/).